# Failed to process package 'compressed_depth_image_transport'

Tags: catkin, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm trying to install ROS Indigo on OS X Yosemite, and executing

```
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

I have come across the following error. How can I resolve it?

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'compressed_depth_image_transport'
==> Building with env: '/Users/Zoe/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/Users/Zoe/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/compressed_depth_image_transport'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/Users/Zoe/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/compressed_depth_image_transport'
[ 25%] Built target compressed_depth_image_transport_gencfg
Linking CXX shared library /Users/Zoe/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/compressed_depth_image_transport/lib/libcompressed_depth_image_transport.dylib
ld: library not found for -ltbb
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/Zoe/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/compressed_depth_image_transport/lib/libcompressed_depth_image_transport.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/compressed_depth_image_transport.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'compressed_depth_image_transport': 
  Command '['/Users/Zoe/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /Users/Zoe/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/compressed_depth_image_transport && /Users/Zoe/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214534/failed-to-process-package-%27compressed_depth_image_transport%27/) by [zoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/23344/zoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23797/alf/) on 2015-10-15**:
I'm currently having the same issue on El Capitan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you're missing `tbb`, did you run `rosdep` to make sure you have all of your dependencies? The step is in the tutorial here:

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source#indigo.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Source.Resolving_Dependencies

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/23344/zoe/) on 2015-07-31**:
Yep I have tbb installed.

When I ran `brew install tbb`, the output is `Warning: tbb-4.3-20150611 already installed`

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-08-03**:
Well, then I'm not sure. Sorry I can't help more, maybe someone else will be able to help you. I'm using the same OS and versions but I'm unable to reproduce this error.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-10-15**:
Since `tbb` is installed, is the environment set up correctly to find it?